# What is the recommended way to serve favicon on a browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, favicon

I'm using npm's `serve-favicon` module to serve `favicon`, but we have also used `react-helmet` to serve the `favicon` module.

I want to know which is the recommended way to serve them and how to each of them does it differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the react-favicon package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-favicon

You can then add it to your initial React render function:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Favicon url="http://oflisback.github.io/react-favicon/public/img/github.ico" />
      <h1>Hello, Favicon!</h1>
    </div>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

If you are using webpack, you can use the [favicons-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin) package

Comment: I want to know which is the best method for serving favicon is it from server-side(nodejs) or client-side(reactjs).

Comment: Id keep it client-side personally - backend code should do backendy things...